# Custom Magento Module

Tags: magento, module, admin

So im creating a module in the backend, I have a shell module created (items in admin top menu and a page to visit.) basically I want to have an input field that the admin can type a number into then click a button "add", this will insert a row into an existing table in the database.

```
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$connection->beginTransaction();
$fields = array();
$fields['name']= 'andy';
$connection->insert('test', $fields);
$connection->commit();
```

I have a table called "test" within my database. If I put the above code into my Controller file, it successfully adds a row to the database when i visit the admin page. But i need to allow the user to input the data that is inserted.

Would I have to move that code into the Model and somehow send the input data to the Model and let that do the work? or not. If this is correct could someone point me to a good place to research sending data to models? (if thats even possible)

iv tried lots of tutorials but they are all way to big for what I need, I dont need to display anything, I just need to have an input box and a save button.

EDIT

i have created a file block/Adminhtml/Form/Edit/Form.php which contains the following . . .

```
class AndyBram_Presbo_Block_Adminhtml_Form_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(
array(
'id' => 'edit_form',
'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/test'),
'method' => 'post',
)
);

$form->setUseContainer(true);
$this->setForm($form);

$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('display', array(
'legend' => 'Display Settings',
'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
));

$fieldset->addField('label', 'text', array(
'name' => 'label',
'label' => 'Label',
));

if (Mage::registry('andybram_presbo')) {
$form->setValues(Mage::registry('andybram_presbo')->getData());
}

return parent::_prepareForm();
}
}
```

then in my controller i have 2 functions like below . . .

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('presbo/adminhtml_form_edit_form'));



    }   
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo 'form data here';
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    }
```

the form is displayed successfully but there is no button to send or say 'do an action'

Further Edit

i have successfully added a submit button to the form that successfully goes to the testAction and echo' "form data here".

how do i then access the data,

iv added the below line

```
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

now if i echo $postData, it just puts "array"

if i echo $postData[0] it doesnt put anything just a blank page

any ideas or pointers?

Comment: Have you already created an admin form?

Comment: i will ammend my post above, it wont fit in a comment.

Comment: $this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name');

Comment: when you use 'param_name' within getParam is this the name of the field within the form?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! Tim you are my saviour, iv been trying for days to get this working, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: strange happening, the module done in the above way using no model, was up and running, iv come back today and when i sign into the admin area, the backend is not rendered i just get this error message -- Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Presbo_Helper_Data' not found in /home1/andybra/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546 -- but iv not changed anything from when it was working?? any ideas? im going to have a go at making a model version today as it looks and feels like the Magento way of doing things.

Comment: it means what it says. there is no `Mage_Presbo_Helper_Data` class. do you need instructions how to create one?

Comment: i figured that but as far as im aware I do have one as it was working, I have a file called Data.php within my Helper folder which contains 

class AndyBram_Presbo_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
 
}

and it is referenced within the config as

<helpers>
    <presbo>
        <class>AndyBram_Presbo_Helper</class>
    </presbo>
</helpers>

but like I said it was working but overnight with no help its decided to loose the helper unless im missing something.

Comment: not quite sure what was going wrong but iv created a skeleton module using an online module builder and copied my code across, now working again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is built as an [MVC framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), thus you're right - you need to pass data from controller to the model, and do not do any DB updates directly in a controller's code. The best source for an example is the own Magento code - you can take any controller action, which saves data to DB to see, how it is done. E.g. check `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/NotificationController.php` method `markAsReadAction()`.

There you can see, that:

- Data is retrieved from the request by calling
  `$this->getRequest()->getParam('id')` - **actually this is the answer
  to the question, how to get the submitted data**
- Data is set to model, and then saved to the DB via call to the
  `$model->setIsRead(1)->save()`

It is strongly encouraged to follow the same approach of working with models. This makes codes much better and easier to support.

Note, that "M" letter of "MVC" architecture in Magento is represented by two layers: Models and Resource Models.

Models:

- Contain business logic of an entity. E.g. adding ten items to a
  Shopping Cart model triggers a discount rule
- Represented by classes with a general name of `<Your_Module>_Model_<Model_Name>`
- If need to work with DB, then extend `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` and have a Resource
  Model, which is responsible for DB communication
- Do not need to have basic save/load methods to be implemented, as the ancestor
  `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` already has all that routines ready to use
- Created via call to `Mage::getModel('<your_module>/<model_name>')`

Resource Models:

- Serve as DB abstraction layer, thus save/load data from DB, perform
  other DB queries
- Extend `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` in order to communicate with DB
- Represented by classes with a general name of
  `<Your_Module>_Model_Resource_<Model_Name>`
- Automatically created by a corresponding model, when it needs to communicate with DB

So, in a controller you care about creating Models only. Resource Models are created by a Model automatically.

And, according to everything said above, your controller should look like:

```
public function testAction()
{
    $model = Mage::getModel('your_module/your_model');
    $model->setName('andy');
    $model->save();
}
```

You can download a fully working example of the thing you need [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/17950262/magento_model_save.zip).

There can be several variations to the code provided, depending on your specific case. But it represents a general approach to implementing the thing you want.

Comment: wow, thank you for the informed response, i have a few questions tho, iv looked through the example code, on line 7 in the testController there is a call to $model->setName(''); but nowhere can i find the function descriptor for setName(''); also would the example not be on the frontend? with using <use>standard</use> within the config file??

Comment: sorry only just reread the last two lines of your comment, it can be changed to admin area, thank you again i will have a play with this approach :)

Comment: Ok, it's good, that you solved the question with admin action controller. Regarding `setName()` - you can call set<AnyField>/get<AnyField> on a model object. This sets/gets a "any_field" entry in `$_data` array in that model, and then saves it to the DB, when `save()` method is called. These method calls are handled by magic method `__call()` which is declared in `Varien_Object` class, being an ancestor of most Magento models (and many other entities as well). You can find the source code in `lib/Varien/Object.php`. I recommend you to install XDebug, it will aid you to trace Magento specifics.

Comment: Hi Andrey, im going through the example you created for me changing names of module and namespace, in the config.xml there is a tag under your_module_resource, the tag looks like <your_table>. Now if the above looks like this -> andybram_presbo_resource, would the table tag look like andybram_table ?? Many Thanks

Comment: The table tag is just a map of table aliases into real table names. It is not influenced by the resource tag name. So, if you make a table declaration like <AAAAA>BBBBB</AAAAA>, then calling `getTable('your_module/AAAAA')` will return you 'BBBBB';